# I can't link my css file to my html file and I couldn't find the solution to my problem in any of the previous posts

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML/CSS and have this problem. I somehow cannot connect my .css to .html file. I tried a lot of things, and spent quite some time on StackOverflow reading about similar problems, but I couldn't find an answer in any of them.

So, to begin with, here's the beginning of my HTML document:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title> My test page </title>
  </head>
 ...
</html>
```

Notes:

- I wrote my own style in a file called `style.css` that is located in the same directory as my .html file.
- The two links above should load some fonts I wanted to use
- I tried moving the link tags throughout the head tag - I tried putting them first, after the script or as they appear now
- I tried changing the order of the link tags

I've spent quite some time trying to figure this out on my own, but just couldn't seem to find a solution that resolves my issue. Can anyone please help?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Right click in your browser and INSPECT ELEMENT the page. You should be able to see if resources cannot be found via the 'Console'. This will help you work out why styles etc are not pulling through.

Comment: The second part of the title makes me laugh :)

Comment: Are you doing this all locally, or uploading the files to a server? If uploading to a server, did you forget to upload your CSS file? And, are the other CSS sources working, like the Google font, or are they all not working?

Comment: @cmp There are no errors displayed in the Console tab.

Comment: @BMartin Eventually, I will upload them on the server. But first I wanted to test things locally. The other CSS sources aren't working either, but I guess that's because I used them in my own css document to set the font to specific elements. So, once my style.css is linked, the others should work too.

Comment: In developer tools, look at the network tab, are the resources loaded? If so try refreshing your cache as HTML and CSS is cached and you'll need to flush the cache for any changes to be apparent.

Comment: @JonP When I go to the network tab and reload it, I can't see any of the css resources (I just see this one image that I used in my html file). I do see the css resources if I go to the style editor tab (if this means anything). Could you please explain how to do the cache flushing?

Comment: Try ctrl+shift+R to fully reload all assets in the browser.

Comment: @EspressoPatronum start again, brand new project. Every little bit you do test and see if it works. Slowly but surely get to the above. If that fails, read a book on web development.

Comment: @BMartin Thanks! Ctrl+Shift+R worked!

Answer (score 1):

while you are with the faulty page open, press F12. This will open the Developer Tools on your browser (assuming you are using Chrome, IE or Firefox).
Check Console tab for any error.
If any, try to solve them (or post them here).
If none, try to append a ./ before style.css in the href property of the link tag.

Comment: Hi, the console is not showing any errors. I tried using href="./style.css" as well, but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Try to create a new folder named styles and put the style.css file in there, linking the new path in the HTML file. Also check if CSS are enabled in your browser and try to refresh the browser cache (CTRL+R or +F5).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title> My test page </title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- Type Something here !-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Write a code in between the body tag and create class and id in style.css to get design in your web page.

Comment: I already have the body, and everything that should be displayed is written in there. I just gave the beginning of the file here, which I thought is relevant for linking the .css file.

Comment: Copy your style.css code and delete the style.css file and then create new file with another name and paste the code and again link with html, hope it should work.